# Show Hide  Form in Application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have problem with show or hide form in Window Form Application.

I start first running loginform at program.cs ( Application.Run(new loginform());), when login success, then show another form ( Main Interface ) and I want to close or hide loginform when second form is shown, but it is not working.

I don know how to do it. Is it a Thread related problem or not?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Myapp
{
   static class Program
   {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Loginfrm());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have 2 forms with Loginfrm and Mainfrm.

In my app, first running is loginfrm are above code:

I want to close or hide Loginfrm when Mainfrm show!, after login success.

Comment: @user1417068 You should accept answers to your questions that were helpful to you. Otherwise people will stop answering your questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: How to prevent main form from showing too early](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495026/c-how-to-prevent-main-form-from-showing-too-early)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a property to your `Loginfrm` class indicating if login was sucessfull or not.
Then, after closing the your `Loginfrm`, you could start another message loop.

Example:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Loginfrm login = new Loginfrm(); 
    Application.Run(login);
    if (login.LogInSuccesfull)
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
}
```

Comment: LogInSuccesfull is variable or Function?

Comment: make it a property indicating if login was sucessfull or not. I don't know how your Loginfrm looks like. Another way is using the DialogResut property. So when the user logs in, set the DialogResult property to OK, other set it to Cancel, and close the form. Then check the DialogResult property in your Main() method instead.

Comment: Application.Run(new MainForm()) not working!

Answer (score 0):

```
// in the mainform add to project form and call it SubForm
SubForm subform = new Subform();
subform.Show();
// in the subform
subform.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Singleton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)

**MainInterface.cs**

```
using System;

public class MainInterface : Form
{
   private static MainInterface Current;

   private MainInterface ()
   {
      if ( LoginForm . Instance != null )
         LoginForm . Instance . Close ();
   }

   public static MainInterface Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (Current == null)
         {
            Current = new MainInterface ();
         }
         return Current;
      }
   }
}
```

**LoginForm.cs**

```
using System;

public class LoginForm: Form
{
   private static LoginForm Current;

   private LoginForm ()
   {

      if ( MainInterface . Instance != null )
         MainInterface . Instance . Close ();
   }

   public static LoginForm Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (Current == null)
         {
            Current = new LoginForm ();
         }
         return Current;
      }
   }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Myapp
{
   static class Program
   {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            LoginForm . Instance . ShowDialog ();

        }
    }
}
```

---

**Switching Forms :**

*From LoginForm*

```
LoginForm . Instance . Hide ();
MainInterface . Instance . ShowDialog ();
```

*From MainInterface*

```
MainInterface . Instance . Hide ();
LoginForm . Instance . ShowDialog ();
```

---

For more that 2 Forms, I suggest using Manager class ( ex. Process ) to Manage and switch between them :)

Regards,

Comment: It's not working, LoginForm.Instance.ShowDialog() not running!,

Comment: How ! What's the error !

Comment: No error, but LoginForm.Instance.ShowDialog() is not running!

Comment: I don't see the Form running. show nothing!